# How to connect to a home IPv4 server over the Internet using IPv6 to bypass Carrier Grade NAT

Tags: networking, proxy, ipv6, tunnel, ipv4

I am looking for a way to be able to connect to a legacy HTTP server that only supports IPv4 connection that is behind an ISP level NAT. My ISP does issue public IPv6 addresses and I am able to successfully connect from an IPv6 client to an IPv6 server on my home network.

Here are the two scenarios I am looking to successfully connect:

1. **IPv6 Client Connecting to a IPv4 server over IPv6** – For this connection, I think the solution is to have a device on my local network with an IPv6 address provide some type of proxy/translation service that would connect to the IPv4 server and convert the data to go over IPv6. (I do not know what this proxy/translation program is or if it even exists.)
2. **IPv4 Client Connecting to a IPv4 server over IPv6** – I think the solution for this would need the solution for scenario 1 plus some way to convert the IPv4 client over to IPv6 so it can connect to the home server.

Network Diagram:
[image: Network Diagram]

I am aware there are ways to do this with VPNs and reverse SSH tunnels, but I am looking for a possibility without the use of these.

Comment: Put a reverse proxy such as nginx in front of the ancient server.

Comment: You can't connect 2 IPv4 systems over IPv6 without a tunnel/VPN.  They are different network stacks.